# id manipulation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a unordered list of `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, `item4`, each with a `div` around it.

```
<ul>
  <div><li>item1</li></div>
  <div class="current"><li>item2</li></div>
  <div><li>item3</li></div>
  <div><li>item4</li></div>
</ul>
```

I want that every time I click itemX, it loads itemX.html and give the div around itemX a current class attribute. Currently I'm writing 4 functions separately for four items, and they look almost the same. So how can I write a general function that just works on any itemX, loads itemX.html and changes its div's attribute? My current code seems so redundant.

Comment: I used div to make the clickable area bigger.

Comment: That's invalid HTML, the li should be direct children of the ul

Comment: How about showing one of your functions? pXL has it pretty much covered (below), but you'll probably get an answer more directly related to your existing code if you _show_ your existing code...

Comment: Get rid of the divs, and apply display:block to the list items to make them full width. Then adapt pXL's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've fixed the HTML problem(li should be sub element of ul). But still for such problem, you need to do:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
});
```

But the correct solution is :

HTML :

```
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li class="current">item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

And add some css to your `li`

Comment: If the click handler is on the li element then `.parent()` would be the ul element...

Comment: Yeah. The solution is given by assuming we are working on a correct html

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid, which will continue to cause problems for you.  Try adding css padding to your LI elements to increase the click area:

```
<style>
    li { padding:10px; }
</style>
```

As to your question:

```
<ul id="targetElement">
    <li data-contentName="item1.html">item one</li>
    <li data-contentName="item2.html">item two</li>
    <li data-contentName="item3.html">item three</li>
    <li data-contentName="item4.html">item four</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#targetElement li').click(function(){  //for all li elements in #targetElement, do this on click
        //remove the active class from the other li's
        $('#targetElement li').removeClass('current');

        //jQuery wrap the current li 
        var $this = $(this);
        //add the class to the current li (the one that was clicked)
        $this.addClass('current');
        //get the name of the file to load
        var fileToLoad = $this.data('contentName');
        //then go about loading the file...
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div li").on('click',function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("current");
  $(this).load($(this).text() + ".html").closest("div").addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: Perhaps throw in a `.siblings().removeClass("current")` (or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, and your html isn't valid. so let me venture a guess at what your trying to do.

```
<ul class="pages"><li>item</li><li>item2</li><li>item3</li></ul>
$(function(){
    $('ul.pages li').click(function(){
        // load html - not user what you mean, so how ever your doing your page load.
          $(this).addClass('someclass');
    });
});
```

Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: Should be `$(this).addClass()`.